# When declaring a range() are you supposed to put a space after the comma/s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Hi guys so I was wondering if you were supposed to have any spaces after commas either in lists, or ranges() or anything that has a comma and a number/letter e.t.c., for example:

```
for num in range(1, 2):
    print(num)
```

The code above is how I do it, as you can see I have a space before my second argument.
Here is how I've seen some people do it...so I'm getting so confused which one is the correct way :(

```
for num in range(1,2):
    print(num)
```

Finally, the code above has no space before the second argument, I'm lost like I've seen both but which one is correct?

I've been having some problems with the PEP8 style guides, I have a lot of questions about it, and for some reason, I feel like I'm actually one of the only ones that have problems with these types of questions about the style guide for python, it seems like everyone else is just so good at it and knows everything.

Comment: PEP8 recommends whitespace after commas, but it is just a style guide. As you've already realized: either way is syntactically valid https://pep8.org/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements

Comment: @AdamSmith oh okay! Thank you for that

Comment: that isn't a declaration... python doesn't have declarations.

Comment: ahh shoot, what should I use instead of that?

Comment: You could say "constructing a range object".

Comment: "creating a range" works too. But don't worry, even experienced programmers might say "declared" in the context of python where no such thing is happening

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ahh okay thank you for clearing it up though